# Call API once on login for Meta Data and store as Enum Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Need to know the best practice for requesting API once on login for Meta Data and store response objects as Enum in Typescript Angular.

Should I use cache feature in `$http` module?

Comment: I think best practice would be to use a ngrx store